# MVC 3 multiple DisplayFor-Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, display-templates

I'm trying to make a custom template for a basket item list. I need a few different templates, as I have different ways of displaying the item, depending on if it's on the webpage or in a mail. Now my problem is, that when I use the default name it works flawlessly.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(b => b.Items)
```

But when I try to add a template name, I get an expection that my templates needs to be of a list type IEnumerable and not BasketItem.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(i => basket.Items, "CustomerItemBaseList")
```

Any ideas where my mistake is, or why it's not possible are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should post the code for your display template(s).

Comment: also, what's your b.Items type? Being plural makes me think that its a collection? wouldn't your template have to be for IEnumerable(Of BasketItem) or something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately that's a limitation of templated helpers. If you specify a template name for a collection property the template no longer applies automatically for each item of the collection. Possible workaround:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Items[i], "CustomerItemBaseList")
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for it to work the other way, but thanks, now I know that I can stop trying =)

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. Phil Haacked's article filled out the remaining details. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That's a good idea, Darin.  I'm lazy though, so I'd like to take it one step further and make an actual helper that wraps this.  I also took out the lambda expression to simplify it for my case, but you can easily add that functionality back in.

```
    public static class DisplayTextListExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForList<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, IEnumerable<string> model, string templateName)
    {
        var tempResult = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            tempResult.Append(html.DisplayFor(m => item, templateName));
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tempResult.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then the actual usage looks like:

```
                                @Html.DisplayForList(Model.Organizations, "infoBtn")
```

Comment: I ran into a couple of minor snags that others might want to know about: To use `DisplayFor` in the helper, it needs `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;` (and Studio won't offer it as an "option to help bind"). To see the helper from the ASP page, you need `<%@ Import Namespace="YourNamespace" %>`

Comment: Ah, okay Chuck.  I use Resharper so if I had that issue, it would have offered to automatically fix it for me.  I highly recommend it for any .NET developer.  I believe there's one or two competing tools as well.  Give them a try too, if you want.

Comment: @DanCsharpster Thanks, just adjusted for any IEnumerable in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I liked Dan's answer but just adjusted slightly as it can work for any IEnumerable:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace YourProject.Whatever
{
    public static class DisplayExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForIEnumerable<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, IEnumerable model, string templateName)
        {
            var tempResult = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                var item1 = item;
                tempResult.Append(html.DisplayFor(m => item1, templateName));
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tempResult.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

And of course:

```
@Html.DisplayForIEnumerable(Model.Organizations, "NameOfYourDisplayTemplate")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another solution useful even more with lists of heterogeneous objects (i.e. BasketItem subclasses), using the **additionalViewData** parameter of the `DisplayFor` method, like:

```
@DisplayFor(b=>b.Items, new { layout="row" })
```

in this way the helper works fine with `IEnumerable<T>`, calling for each item (subclass of T) the relative *DisplayTemplate*, passing it the **additionalViewData** values in the `ViewData` dictionary.

The template could so output different code for different layout values.

In the example above the template named View\Shared\DisplayTemplates\**BasketItem** (or the name of the subclass) should be like this:

```
@model MyProject.BasketItem // or BasketItem subclass
@{ 
    string layout = ViewData["layout"] as string ?? "default";

    switch(layout)
    {
        case "row":
            <div class="row">
            ...
            </div>
        break;
        // other layouts
        ...
        default: // strongly recommended a default case
            <div class="default-view>
            ...
            </div>
        break;
    }
}
```

It is strongly recommended to provide always a default code.

I hope this suggestion could help.